# Swift timeInterval formatter

Tags: macos, swift, date

I can get the date in de date picker, calculate the time left and put in a label. This gives seconds:

```
let timeLeft = datePicker.dateValue.timeIntervalSinceNow
countingLabel.stringValue = "seconds left: \(timeLeft)"
```

**How to format "timeLeft"?**

```
I tried this and it does not work:
var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
let timeLeft2 = formatter.stringFromDate(timeLeft)
```

Comment: the `timeIntervalSinceNow` is not an `NSDate` instance but a primitive `NSTimeInterval`, therefore you cannot use it directly with an `NSDateFormatter`, first you need to convert it back to `NSDate` if you'd like to get it formatted as date. _(it is the thousandth good example why the type should not be ever bypassed when you create a `var` or a `let`)._

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`NSDateComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDateComponentsFormatter_class/index.html). From the
documentation:

> An `NSDateComponentsFormatter` object takes quantities of time and
> formats them as a user-readable string. Use a date components
> formatter to create strings for your app’s interface.

Example:

```
let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .Full
formatter.allowedUnits = .CalendarUnitSecond | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitHour

let pickedDate = datePicker.dateValue
let now = NSDate()
let formattedTimeLeft = formatter.stringFromDate(now, toDate: pickedDate)!

// Example result : 1:06:50
```

There are some more output formats available, e.g.

```
.Abbreviated :  1h 6m 50s
.Short :        1 hr, 6 min, 50 secs
.Full :         1 hour, 6 minutes and 50 seconds
```

**Update for Swift 4** and later:

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .full // or .short or .abbreviated
formatter.allowedUnits = [.second, .minute, .hour]

let pickedDate = datePicker.date
let now = Date()
let formattedTimeLeft = formatter.string(from: now, to: pickedDate)!
```

Comment: This gives me: Optional(20 hours, 56 minutes, 8 seconds) Why Optional and parentesis and how to get rid of it?

Comment: @Nrc: `stringFromDate()` returns an *optional* string, so you have to unwrap it with `!`. I have updated the code.

Comment: It works very well, thank you. Do you know how to make something happen if the time left arrives to 0?. Something like: if formattedTimeLeft == 0 { }

Comment: @Nrc: That is a completely different question. You can use a timer (NSTimer) or perhaps local notifications (UILocalNotification). Please post a new question if necessary.

Comment: Swift 5 -> let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .full
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute]

Answer (score 0):

To get timeLeft you should use two time components and get their differnece as follow:

```
let todayComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.DayCalendarUnit | .MonthCalendarUnit | .YearCalendarUnit | .CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond | , fromDate : NSDate())

var pickedDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.DayCalendarUnit | .MonthCalendarUnit | .YearCalendarUnit | .CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond | , fromDate : datePicker.dateValue)

pickedDateComponents.second  =  pickedDateComponents.second - todayComponents.second 
pickedDateComponents.minute = pickedDateComponents.minute - todayComponents.minute 
pickedDateComponents.hour = pickedDateComponents.hour - todayComponents.hour 
pickedDateComponents.day =pickedDateComponents.day - todayComponents.day 
pickedDateComponents.month = pickedDateComponents.month - todayComponents.month 
pickedDateComponents.year = pickedDateComponents.year - todayComponents.year 

let timeLeft = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(pickedDateComponents)!
```

Comment: this gives me the same result that: let myDate = datePicker.dateValue  That is the time of the date picker that I can format later with no problem. The problem I have is with the let timeLeft, that is the difference between now and the time picked in the day picker.

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: I cannot even build. There is errors in every line. First line: Expected expression after operator...